# Textfield, Button or other elements user interaction not working in WKWebView for HTML String in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm loading HTML String on WKWebView. It's loading perfectly. But when i try to press any text-field or button user-interaction is not working.

I'm not sure it's a problem with Html content or swift code. I've seen lots of solutions but none of them didn't solve my issue.

Here is my code...

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        openDetailsIn(webView: webView)
    }

func openDetailsIn(webView: WKWebView) {

let htmlstring = """
     <html>
     <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            #st-payment input.st-error {
                background-color: #ffc6c7;
                border: 2px solid #ffb5b5;
            }

            #st-message .st-error {
                background: #ffcdcd;
                border: 2px solid #ffb5b5;
                padding: 4px 4px 4px 28px !important;
            }
        </style>
     </head>

     <body>
     <h2>Fill you details</h2>
     <div id="st-message"></div>
     <form id="st-payment" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="0"/>
                    <input type="text" disabled readonly value="gbp"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Card Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" data-st-field="pan" autocomplete="off"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Expiry Month</td>
                <td><input type="text" data-st-field="expirymonth" autocomplete="off"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Expiry Year</td>
                <td><input type="text" data-st-field="expiryyear" autocomplete="off"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CVV</td>
                <td><input type="text" data-st-field="securitycode" autocomplete="off"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="mybtn"/>
     </form>
     <script src="https://webservices.net/js/st.js"></script>
     <script>
        new SecureTrading.Standard({
            sitereference: "",
            locale:        ""
        });
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
     """

    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlstring, baseURL: nil)
}

extension PaymentGatewayViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        //Show loader
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        //Hide loader
    }
```

}

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your solution and worked perfectly in my Xcode working with iOS 12.4.
Can you create a sample project in order to help you to figure out what is happening in your Xcode?

Comment: It's working for me as well - Issue is with, I added WKWebView in UIView container in xib. Later I realized and replaced WKWebView without UIView container. Then user-interaction started working fine. It's really really wared behaviour.

Comment: Ahhhh that was the problem! I added the WKWebView directly to the view of the view controller.